# How to monitor multiple node insertions at different levels in dom using MutationObserver

Tags: javascript

I have a parent node  in my dom. I have to call a method when a specific element is inserted in the parent node (newly inserted node is not a direct child, its a subtree, may be present at 2/3 level deep).

I have a code for single element insertion which works as expected

```
var parentNode = jQuery('.parent-node');
var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    if (parentNode.find('.sub-class-1')[0] !== undefined) {
        //call method       
        this.disconnect();
    }
 }).observe(parentNode[0], {childList:true, subtree: true });
```

But i want to execute callbacks for multiple sub elements creations. i tried this by using forEach on sub-class elements array.

```
arr.forEach(function (ob) {
    new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
        if (parentNode.find(ob.className)[0] != undefined) {
            //ob.callback()
            this.disconnect();
        }
    }).observe(parentNode[0], { attributes:false, childList: true, subtree: true });
});
```

But after processing one subclass, it does not processes the rest subclasses. I guess we can only create on object on particular node.
So, how to detect all this nodes on creation to execute specific callbacks using MutationObserver or is there any better alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please try this,

```
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };
var observers = [];
function createObserver(target, index) {
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    var $this = this;
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        if (parentNode.find('.sub-class-1')[0] !== undefined) {     
            $this.disconnect();
        }else{
            observers.push($this);
        }
    });
});
observer.observe(target, config);
}
$('.parent-node').each(function(i, el) {
createObserver(el, i)
});
```

Comment: Instead of looping mutations, i looped my custom arr  array object & i set the target to document.body. Then it worked. looping mutations did not gave me correct result Nor setting target to parent-node. I am not sure why?

Comment: @MayurPatil Can you share your array with me? and how do you create the arr?

Comment: arr = [className: '.subclass-1', processed:0, callback: callback1, className: '.subclasss-2', processed:0, callback: callback2]  and so on

Comment: Your array doesnt have dom element hence you cant use that maybe i tought missunderstand you. Hence can you share your full code in fiddle

Comment: Hi if you would like to reach which node is changed then you can use mutations please try below code  `new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
            console.log(mutations);`